# JTable setPreferredWidth causing an extra column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is my code

```
JTable table = new JTable(attributeValues, attributeNamesString);

table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

for(int z=0;z<table.getColumnCount();z++){
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setMaxWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setPreferredWidth(100);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, I get an additional column on the screen which stretches to the window size. I'm not sure where it's come from or how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Does this not happen if you leave out `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setPreferredWidth(100);`?

Comment: Well, it seems to happen as a combination of the setPreferredWidth() and table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF). 

If I don't disable AutoResize, I still have a JTable that stretches horizontally to the frame, but with empty space after the four columns.

What I was hoping to achieve to have is a JTable that has a total width of 100*numColumns.

Comment: Have you tried to not set the maximum width of the "Delete" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is caused by the `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setPreferredWidth(100);` call? I suspect (although I haven't tried it myself) that it is more likely caused by `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(z).setMaxWidth(100);`, as this sets the columns' *maximum* width (adding up to 4 x 100px in your case) while the table itself is stretched to more than 4 x 100px.

If you do not want the table itself to be wider than 4 x 100px, can you not set the maximum size of the table as well (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize(java.awt.Dimension))?

Comment: it seems to happen as a combination of the setPreferredWidth() and table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF). If I don't disable AutoResize, I still have a JTable that stretches horizontally to the frame, but with empty space after the four columns. 
If I remove the maxWidth, I just go back to having a JTable that stretches to the screen with equal width columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I set the maximum size of the table itself, it works. I was using setPreferredSize on the table earlier.